# Want to execute awk from tcl

Tags: awk, tcl

I want to execute the following line in tcl:

`exec awk -F"[][]" '/dB/ { print $2 }' <(amixer sget Master)`

but error: `missing close-brace` appears.

Then I changed it for this:

`exec awk -F"[][]" {/dB/ { print $2 }} <(amixer sget Master)`

Changing the single quotes with curly brackets. Now the error is:

couldn't read file `"(amixer": no such file or directory`

Then I changed to this:

`exec awk -F{[][]} {/dB/ { print $2 }} <(amixer sget Master)`

Still the same error as the latter.

I am really struggling with tcl parsing mechanism of the `exec` command. Please help. Thank you.

amixer sget Master output:

```
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 64
  Mono: Playback 39 [61%] [-25.00dB] [on]
```

Comment: Process substitution is done by the shell. Try invoking bash like: `exec bash -c "awk .... <( ... )"`

Comment: I tried, but now I get another error: `can't read "2": no such variable`

Comment: Escape the dollar, with `\$2`

Comment: What is the output of `amixer sget Master`?

Comment: I assume you use GNU awk? If not your `-F` expression will only consider `[` as separator. What would `[][]` match anyway? Since it's treated as a `regexp` afaik, it would match two empty character lists. Hence nothing?

Comment: @Qben: It seems to match a character list containing the characters `[` and `]`...at least for me `$2` returned `76%` for the line `Front Left: Playback 56 [76%] [-18.00dB] [on]` whereas `$3` got evaluated to `-18.00dB` using GNU `awk` 3.1.8.

Comment: Whilst escaping `\$2` tclsh hangs and after pressing Ctrl-C error: `awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: division by zero attempted'`

Comment: @milarepa: Did you use double quoutes (`"`) for the `awk` code (see my answer)?

Comment: @Qben: I cannot correct my previous comment anymore, but I was going to write `$4` instead of `$3`. As you would expect, `$3` returns the space between the 1st `]` and the 2nd `[`.

Comment: @sg-lecram indeed, did not have to output to test myself before I wrote the comment. I would expect the inner `][` to be escaped. Well, that belong in a different question. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The shell and Tcl have quite different syntaxes, and this is an area where it matters.
The correct transliteration of the shell invocation:

```
awk -F"[][]" '/dB/ { print $2 }' <(amixer sget Master)
```

is this:

```
exec amixer sget Master | awk {-F[][]} {/dB/ { print $2 }}
```

In partixular, Tcl and the shell have different ideas about how to quote things and what things need to be quoted. Moreover, it's far easier to make `awk` just take its input from stdin rather than trying to make Tcl handle pipes right to do the redirection in exactly the way the shell is doing (you *can* do it, but it's hard work and really not worth the bother for something this simple).

Of course, you might instead use Tcl to do the parsing as it has reasonable regular expression matching support. For example, this stores the decibel level in the variable `decibels`:

```
set mixer "Master"
regexp {\[([\d.]+)dB\]} [exec amixer sget $mixer] -> decibels
```

Comment: It works finally !!!! `exec amixer sget Master | awk {-F[][]} {/dB/ { print $2 }}` Thank you @Donal Fellows

Answer (score 0):

Thx to Donal Felows I figured out that the problem was **not** the *shell quoting* **but** the *tcl  syntax*. So I revised my whole answer to suggest the following:

```sh
exec /bin/bash -c {amixer sget Master | awk -F"[][]" '/dB/{print $2}'}
```

or if you like to use process substitution instead of the pipe:

```sh
exec /bin/bash -c {awk -F"[][]" '/dB/{print $2}' <(amixer sget Master)}
```

Both lines use the `{...}` syntax to escape the `bash` code from `tcl` interpretation and thus allow normal `bash` code in between.

I am not sure if this is the  best way to do it, since it basically shifts all the work from `tcl` to `bash`, but at least this is working for me (using `tcl` 8.5.13-r1, GNU `bash` 4.2.45(1) and GNU `awk` 4.0.1).

Comment: It gives me this error: `couldn't read file "(amixer": no such file or directory`.

Comment: did you try to substitute `$SHELL` with your actual shell (e.g. `/bin/sh`)? Can you give a MWE for me to test my code under real-life conditions?

Comment: Yes. I change the $SHELL variable. I tried the update and tcl complains: `extra characters after close-quote`. Sorry, what's WME?

Comment: @milarepa: Sorry for using an abbreviation without explaining it first. MWE is short for minimal working example - a piece of code that I can copy/paste to test your actual problem. In this case a short tcl script containing the line causing problems and how you call it.

Comment: After I start having problems, I only test that line on tclsh, so there no is other code involved.

Comment: This answer is dead wrong; it's using shell syntax instead of Tcl syntax.

Comment: @DonalFellows and other downvoters: Thx for poiting out the error ing my first answer. Please check out my revised answer.